# Moving folders to other folders with python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a program that will clean up my desktop by moving everything into corresponding folders that are within another folder. For example, when you run the script, it makes a folder on your desktop called "desktop items" and then within that folder are subfolders such as "documents" "applications" "code", etc. Right now I have the individual files on my desktop being stored correctly, but I'm not sure how I would handle the folders. I just want to store the already made folders within the "desktop items" folder. Thanks!

Comment: check `shutil` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `shutil` module. The function [`shutil.move(src, dst)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) will do the trick.

Where `src` will be the already made folder and `dst` will be the folder "desktop items".

**Edited:**
For an arbitrary number of folders you can use module `os` like this:

```
for elem in os.list("desktop_path"):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join("desktop_path", elem)):
        shutil.move(os.path.join("desktop_path", elem), "desktop items folder")
```

Comment: how would I implement that for an arbitrary number of folders with arbitrary names?

Comment: `"desktop_path/" + elem` would look better with `os.path.join("desktop_path",elem)`